# How many primes of the form $2^p+p$ exist with $p$ prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I know that if $p = 6k + 5$ with $k$ integer, then $(2^p+p) \mod 6 \equiv 1$. I think this means that $2^p+p$ could be prime. My question is: how many numbers of primes can be written like this? Is it a finite or infinite number?

Comment: $2^n+n$ is prime for $n = 3,5,9,15$. I don't think we know if there are infinitely many such primes, and even less for $n$ prime.

Comment: See [OEIS A$52007$](http://oeis.org/A052007).